# amqp pika hangs at basic_publish()

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, pika

Recently upgraded to RabbitMQ version 3.2.0 from 2.x previously.  The version of pika being used is 0.9.13.  Previously when sending "large" messages (20k - 40k bytes...so maybe not that large) it would send the message without any problems.  Now with the new RabbitMQ server the message will not send and instead hangs at basic_publish and will not send the message to the server; small messages do not seem to be an issue.

This is causing some frustration because the only thing that has changed is effectively upgrading the server to a newer version. 
I noticed that RabbitMQ states on their site that a limit to frame_max size is now set by default.  I tried changing my /etc/rabbitmq/rabbit.config file to eliminate the frame_max:

```
[{rabbit, [{frame_max ,0 }]}].
```

Then of course restart the service:

```
service rabbitmq-server restart
```

I was able to verify this change by using:

```
rabbitmqctl environment
```

This did not solve my issue however as the same problem still persists; I can't send large messages to my rabbitmq server.  Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Comment: You should rather use answers in case you find the solution to a question you asked. There is no problem with answering your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that my answer in my question was deleted so here is the resolution:

I had to upgrade to pika 0.9.14 ; this solved my problem.  There were some issues of compatibility with pika 0.9.13 and a recent upgrade to rabbitmq version 3+

This version of pika can be found **[here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pika)**

Answer (score 1):

The problem, found by the OP himself, was solved by upgrading to pika 0.9.14.

Comment: Yep, that is correct. It was a socket issue that caused this. This is taken from the changelog => ```Major issue with socket buffer refactor in 0.9.13 (#328) fixes by cooper6581 and Erik Andersson``` https://pika.readthedocs.org/en/latest/